# Limit the selection of checkboxes based on the selection of other checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 checkboxes (All, Friday, Saturday, and Sunday) and would like to limit the selection that a user can select to: All and no other selection OR any combination of Friday to Sunday but All is not allowed to be selected.

Ex 1. 
All is checked
Friday, Saturday, Sunday are not allowed to be checked

Ex 2. 
Friday and Sunday are checked
All is not allowed to be checked

The following JS code is working but I was wondering if there was a better/faster/more elegant way to write the following JS.

```
Select Days:<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="All">All</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Friday">Friday</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Saturday">Saturday</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Sunday">Sunday</label>
```

JS

```
<script>
    /* Only allow All or (Friday, Saturday, Sunday) */
    $("input[name='consultantDays'").on('change', function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 'All') {
            $("input[name='consultantDays'").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        } else {
            $("input[value='All'").not(this).prop('checked', false);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working perfectly, but you have missed the closing brackets on the attribute selectors.

```
$("input[name='consultantDays']").not(this).prop('checked', false);
                              ^
} else {
$("input[value='All']").not(this).prop('checked', false);
                    ^
```

```js
/* Only allow All or (Friday, Saturday, Sunday) */
$("input[name='consultantDays'").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'All') {
    $("input[name='consultantDays']").not(this).prop('checked', false);
  } else {
    $("input[value='All']").not(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select Days:<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="All">All</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Friday">Friday</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Saturday">Saturday</label>

<br>

<label><input type="checkbox" name="consultantDays" value="Sunday">Sunday</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. Any opinion about improving the code or would you write it this way?